# Second router losing signal when first router drops connection

Tags: networking, wireless-router

I have added a second router to my home network, as my first does not allow DLNA. I have an ethernet running from my first router (provided by Bell) to the second (TP-Link). I have wireless disabled on the first, and enabled on the second. The second router is where I have connected my PC and network hard drive.

In my area, the phone cables are old, which causes the Bell signal to drop, about once per day, just for a half second. It wouldn't be a problem if I only had the one router. The problem is, however, that when this happens, my TP-Link will not reconfigure itself, and I can't connect to the TP-Link.  The SSID will still be visible.

Any way to force the TP-Link to reconfigure when this happens?  I had tried to use a static IP from the first router to the second, but it was causing problems and I gave up. Would this fix the problem?